# Are there views with multiple models in swing? (TreeModel and TreeSelectionModel)

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

TreeModel and TreeSelectionModel are both Types of models. You can acquire those be using

```
tree.getModel();
```

and

```
tree.getSelectionModel();
```

where tree is an Object of the type JTree.
There are also setter-methodes for both of them.
My Question is:
If I'm right in concluding that tree has two models (the TreeModel und the TreeSelectionModel), how does this go together with the MVC-Pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there actually ARE two models for the `JTree` (and `JTable` and `JList` as well). However, the `TreeSelectionModel` is considered as a GUI model whereas the `TreeModel` is an actual application-data model, as explained there: [A Swing Architecture Overview - Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html).

I would assume that you can think of that achitecture in this way: the model you manipulate through `JTree#getSelectionModel()` is actually something like a `Decorator` wrapping the `JTree#getModel()`. In such a case, you would actually have the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|    +-----------+                              |
|    | TreeModel >-------(relation: Decorator)  |
|    +-----^-----+       |                      |
|          |             |                      |
|          |   +---------v----------+           |
|          |   | TreeSelectionModel |           |
|          |   +---------^----------+           |
|          |             |                      |
|    +-----^-------------v----+                 |
|    |        Presenter       |                 |
|    +------------^-----------+                 |
|                 |                             |
|    +------------v-----------+                 |
|    |        TreeView        |                 |
|    +------------------------+                 |
|                                               |
+------------------- JTree ---------------------+
```

I'm using a `Presenter` instead of a `Controller` 'cause it's my way to implement the MVC pattern (well, I guess it's an MVP, then) when a `View` is also a `Controller`.

This most certainly is not the exact way it's implemented but I think it might work in a similar manner. Anyway, I think it's still well-implemented enough to not have to worry about using them :)